# how to Customise the NSSegmentedControl font and background color

Tags: cocoa, nssegmentedcontrol

I want to customise the background colour and text color for NSSegmentedControl.
There is option to do this for IOS but not found anything for OSX.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the font directly e.g.:

```
segmentedControl.font = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:24];
```

To set the background color:

```
segmentedControl.wantsLayer = YES;
segmentedControl.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: Is there some specific context in which this works? I'm trying to change a segementedControl's layer background colour as you describe but can't get it to work at all.

Comment: Just retested - works fine. Nothing special about the context. XCode 10.1, MacOS 10.13.6

Comment: @jeff-h, make sure you're setting `segmentedControl.wantsLayer = YES`. It's working for me in Xcode 13.4.1 on macOS 12.3.1.

Comment: Thanks @StewartMacdonald for the prompt. I tried it again, and yes, works perfectly as written. No clue what I was doing wrong back in 2020! What I'd really like to do is have *no* background, but I think that's a different thing entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Basically in your XIB inside attribute inspector of segmented control inside tint propery you can set the color or else samething you can achieve programatically as well.

Comment: Any hint on how to achieve it programmatically?

Comment: I think this answer only applies to UISegmentedControl in iOS, not NSSegmentedControl for OSX.  Apple's docs show no results when you search for "color" in NSSegmentedControl or NSControl which it inherits from.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSegmentedControl_Class/